# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 17: invalid start byte

Tags: 18.04, nginx, add-apt-repository

I want to install Nginx together with Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 18.04 and already installed this package:

```
software-properties-common
```

When I try to use the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
```

to add the repository for certbot, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 107, in <module>
    sp = SoftwareProperties(options=options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 122, in __init__
    self.sourceslist = SourcesList()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 273, in __init__
    self.matcher = SourceEntryMatcher(matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/sourceslist.py", line 457, in __init__
    dist = DistInfo(f, base_dir=matcherPath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distinfo.py", line 261, in __init__
    component.set_description(_(value))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 17: invalid start byte
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Seems to be network issue. I can't reproduce your problem on clean 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Okay, i found my solution: 

there was a problem with my locales, with this command the problem could be solved:

LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

The answer was posted in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/1728919) by [Roland Frühauf](https://askubuntu.com/users/850943/roland-fr%c3%bchauf):

> There was a problem with my locales, with this command the problem could be solved:
>
> ```
> LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
> ```